# how to get radio input value that the selector gotten using find() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I try to get value from children element that each child (item) has input fields with the same `name`. To do that, I used each() function. I get problem when retrieving value from radio input, I get the value from radio input that shouldn't. Here the code

```
<div class="accordion" id="menu-ui-sortable" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel menu-item">
        <a class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="heading-menu-item-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-ui-sortable" href="#menu-item-settings-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu-item-settings-1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Menu Item 1</h4>
            <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
            <i class="item-type pull-right">Halaman Web</i>
        </a>

        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_type" value="page"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_page_id" value="12"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_content_id" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_url" value="www.example.com/page-12"/>

        <div id="menu-item-settings-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-menu-item-1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label>Label Navigasi</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_title" value="label 1"/>

                <label>Atribut Judul</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_attr_title" value="attr 1"/>

                <p class="menu_item_target"><label><input type="checkbox" name="menu_item_target" value="1" checked=""> Buka tautan di tab baru</label></p>

                <label>CSS Classes/Icon</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_classes" value="fa fa-glass"/>

                <label>Letak CSS Classes/Icon</label>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="left" checked=""> Sebelah kiri label</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="right"> Sebelah kanan label</label>
                </div>

                <label class="move-button-handle">
                    <span>Pindahkan: </span>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-up" data-dir="up">Naik Satu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-down" data-dir="down">Turun Satu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-top" data-dir="top">Urutan Pertama</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-bottom" data-dir="top">Urutan Terakhir</a>
                </label>

                <div class="menu-item-actions submitbox">
                    <p class="link-to-original">Asli: <a class="a-link" href="http://wordpress.dev/new-page-page/">new page page</a></p>
                    <a class="item-delete danger-highlight" href="#">Hapus</a><span> | </span>
                    <a class="item-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel menu-item">
        <a class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="heading-menu-item-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-ui-sortable" href="#menu-item-settings-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu-item-settings-2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Menu Item 2</h4>
            <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
            <i class="item-type pull-right">Homepage Content</i>
        </a>

        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_type" value="homepage-content"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_page_id" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_content_id" value="4"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_url" value="#content-4"/>

        <div id="menu-item-settings-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-menu-item-2">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label>Label Navigasi</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_title" value="label 2"/>

                <label>Atribut Judul</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_attr_title" value="attr 2"/>

                <p class="menu_item_target"><label><input type="checkbox" name="menu_item_target" value="1"> Buka tautan di tab baru</label></p>

                <label>CSS Classes/Icon</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_classes" value="fa fa-search"/>

                <label>Letak CSS Classes/Icon</label>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="left"> Sebelah kiri label</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="right" checked=""> Sebelah kanan label</label>
                </div>

                <label class="move-button-handle">
                    <span>Pindahkan: </span>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-up" data-dir="up">Naik Satu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-down" data-dir="down">Turun Satu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-top" data-dir="top">Urutan Pertama</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-bottom" data-dir="top">Urutan Terakhir</a>
                </label>

                <div class="menu-item-actions submitbox">
                    <a class="item-delete danger-highlight" id="delete-2" href="#">Hapus</a><span> | </span>
                    <a class="item-cancel" id="cancel-2" href="#">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel menu-item">
        <a class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="heading-menu-item-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-ui-sortable" href="#menu-item-settings-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu-item-settings-3">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Menu Item 3</h4>
            <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
            <i class="item-type pull-right">Tautan Tertentu</i>
        </a>

        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_type" value="custom-link"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_page_id" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu_item_content_id" value=""/>

        <div id="menu-item-settings-3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-menu-item-3">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label>URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_url" value="www.example.com"/>

                <label>Label Navigasi</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_title" value="label 3"/>

                <label>Atribut Judul</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_attr_title" value="attr 3"/>

                <p class="menu_item_target"><label><input type="checkbox" name="menu_item_target" value="1"> Buka tautan di tab baru</label></p>

                <label>CSS Classes/Icon</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_item_classes" value="fa fa-files"/>

                <label>Letak CSS Classes/Icon</label>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="left" checked=""> Sebelah kiri label</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="right"> Sebelah kanan label</label>
                </div>

                <label class="move-button-handle">
                    <span>Pindahkan: </span>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-up" data-dir="up">Naik Satu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-down" data-dir="down">Turun Satu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-top" data-dir="top">Urutan Pertama</a>
                    <a href="#" class="a-link menus-move menus-move-bottom" data-dir="top">Urutan Terakhir</a>
                </label>

                <div class="menu-item-actions submitbox">
                    <a class="item-delete danger-highlight" id="delete-3" href="#">Hapus</a><span> | </span>
                    <a class="item-cancel" id="cancel-3" href="#">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<button id="menu-nav-action" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>
```

The js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#menu-ui-sortable").collapse().sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-sortable-placeholder",
        start: function(evt, ui ){
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
        },
        helper: function(evt, ui){
            var $clone =  $(ui).clone();
            $clone .css('position','absolute');
            return $clone.get(0);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#menu-nav-action', function (evt) {
        var menuNav = [];
        var ctn = 0;

        $("#menu-ui-sortable > div.panel.menu-item").each(function () {

            var menu_item_target = $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_target"]');
            var menu_item_target_ = menu_item_target.is(':checked') ? menu_item_target.val() : '0';

            var menu_item_classes_position = $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_classes_position"]');
            var menu_item_classes_position_ = '';

            for (var i = 0, length = menu_item_classes_position.length; i < length; i++) {
                if (menu_item_classes_position[i].checked) {
                    menu_item_classes_position_ = menu_item_classes_position[i].value;
                    console.log(menu_item_classes_position_);
                    break;
                }
            }

            /* Using each() function not work too */
            /*$(menu_item_classes_position).each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    menu_item_classes_position_ = $(this).val();
                    console.log(menu_item_classes_position_);
                }
            });*/

            menuNav.push({
                nav_label: $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_title"]').val(),
                nav_title_attr: $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_attr_title"]').val(),
                nav_open_new_tab: menu_item_target_,
                nav_css_classes: $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_classes"]').val(),
                nav_css_classes_position: menu_item_classes_position_,
                nav_type: $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_type"]').val(),
                nav_link: $(this).find('input[name="menu_item_url"]').val(),
                nav_order: ctn});
            ctn++;
        });
        console.log(menuNav);
        alert(JSON.stringify(menuNav));
    });

});
```

Here the output:

```
[
    {
        "nav_label":"label 1",
        "nav_title_attr":"attr 1",
        "nav_open_new_tab":"1",
        "nav_css_classes":"fa fa-glass",
        "nav_css_classes_position":"", // **this should be "left"**
        "nav_type":"page",
        "nav_link":"www.example.com/page-12",
        "nav_order":0
    },
    {
        "nav_label":"label 2",
        "nav_title_attr":"attr 2",
        "nav_open_new_tab":"0",
        "nav_css_classes":"fa fa-search",
        "nav_css_classes_position":"", // **this should be "right"**
        "nav_type":"homepage-content",
        "nav_link":"#content-4",
        "nav_order":1
    },
    {
        "nav_label":"label 3",
        "nav_title_attr":"attr 3",
        "nav_open_new_tab":"0",
        "nav_css_classes":"fa fa-files",
        "nav_css_classes_position":"left",
        "nav_type":"custom-link",
        "nav_link":"www.example.com",
        "nav_order":2
    }
]
```

Based the HTML, the correct value for `nav_css_classes_position` in each item are "left", "right", and "left".

Here the demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekosubha/wLmywmtr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using same radio names[name="menu_item_classes_position"]for every group. Use different names for each group.

In your example, there are 3 menu items containing radio buttons wrapped in accordion. But these radio buttons are acting as a one group. that is,when you select radio button of second menu item, it will deselect radio button of first menu item.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is due to this

```
<input type="radio" name="menu_item_classes_position" value="left" checked="checked"> Sebelah kiri label</label>
```

All of your radio element belongs to same group **name="menu_item_classes_position"** , as per the documentation of the radio input only one button of a group can be checked at a time. This is why only in menu 3 the radio button is checked. You can confirm this in your fiddle as well.

You should give each set of radio button in a menu a different name to select the correct value.